# Locally-hosted RSS mirror/proxy, HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: http, rss, podcast

I picked up an Internet Radio (Grace Digital device using Reciva Internet Radio) from Goodwill and discovered that I can add podcasts of my choosing to it. However, it only supports RSS streams over HTTP. (No HTTPS support)

Is there a moderately simple method of hosting an RSS feed on HTTP (NOT open to the web, mind you) that would be updated from the main podcast's HTTPS RSS feed? Is this something that I would need to build (e.g. code) from scratch, especially given the non-secure requirement, and the preference to run this all locally, not over the Internet?